# How to store coordinates in MFC-single-document?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am doing a small project of drawing tool.

I use line to draw a polygon, so I use `CList<CPoint,CPoint> m_Points` to store the end point of each line.

Here is my code:

```
void CDrawToolView::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
   .
   .
   .
   CList<CPoint,CPoint> m_Points; 
   m_Points.AddTail(point);
   . 
   .
   .
}
```

And I want to pass the points to a dialog. In the calling function:

```
void CDrawToolView::OnEditProperty()
{
    CPropertyDlg dlg;  
    dlg.Points = m_Points;
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {   
        m_Points = dlg.Points;
    }
}
```

Then in the dialog, when clicking OK, read all the points from `CList<CPoint,CPoint> Points`:

```
void CPropertyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CList<CPoint,CPoint> Points; 
    Points.AddTail(polypoint);
    POSITION pos = Points.GetHeadPosition();
    while( pos != NULL )
    {
       int i = 0;
       element = Points.GetNext(pos);
       polygon_x[i] = element.x;
       polygon_y[i] = element.y;
       i ++;
    }
}
```

When running program, `CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'` , how can I fix that problem?

Besides, can I use this method to pass points to the dialog?

Comment: MFC: ah, so glad I don't have to wear that hair-shirt

Comment: Harsh as it may sound, this is not the type of question to ask on stackoverflow. You have asked several questions all revolving around the same theme: How to pass complex data in C++. I would suggest to pick up a good introductory [book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and work through that.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `m_Points` member of CPropertyDlg as `CList<CPoint,CPoint>*` and pass pointer to this dialog:

```
void CDrawToolView::OnEditProperty()
{
    CPropertyDlg dlg;  
    dlg.Points = &m_Points;
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {   
        //m_Points = dlg.Points;   // not necessary because Points is changed in-place
    }
}
```

The problem in your existing code, that you are trying to pass `CList` by value, which requires copying the whole object. This is not allowed by MFC authors by making `operator=` private.

BTW, if you are trying to implement drawing functionality, check out MFC sample DRAWCLI.